# Not able to access File with Singleton pattern

Tags: java, file, junit, singleton

I wrote java class that simulate Hard disk using file . 
The Hard disk calss is Singleton . I am now using Junit to test some other class in the project and need to use the Hard disk calss .
From some reason every time I use the method   HardDisk.getInstance();
in the Junit I get the error IOException. if I delete the file the error changes to fileNotFound, so I know the class is kinda of working .

Class Junit

```
import com.hit.algorithm.IAlgoCache;
import com.hit.algorithm.LRUAlgoCacheImpl;
import com.hit.memoryunits.*;

import junit.framework.Assert;

import static org.junit.Assert.*;

import java.io.IOException;

import org.junit.Test;

public class MemoryManagementUnitTest {
    @Test
    public void testGetPages() throws IOException {
    HardDisk.getInstance();

    }

}
```

class Hard Disk

```
package com.hit.memoryunits;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.Map.Entry;


public class HardDisk{

    static final String DEFAULT_FILE_NAME="src\\main\\test\\hdPages.txt";
    static final int _SIZE=1000;
    //private static final HardDisk instance=new HardDisk();
    private static  HardDisk instance=new HardDisk();
    LinkedHashMap<Long,Page<byte[]>> harDiskMap;


    @SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked"})
    private HardDisk(){
        harDiskMap = new LinkedHashMap<>(_SIZE);
        try{
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(DEFAULT_FILE_NAME);
            ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
            try{
                while(true){
                    Page<byte[]> temp = (Page<byte[]>)in.readObject();
                    harDiskMap.put(temp.getPageId(), temp);
                }
            }
            finally{
                    in.close();
            }
        }
        catch (ClassNotFoundException e){
            System.out.println("ClassNotFoundException");
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e1){
            System.out.println("FileNotFoundException");
        }
        catch(IOException e2){
            System.out.println("IOException");
        }
    }

    public static HardDisk getInstance(){
        return HardDisk.instance;
    }


    private void writeHd() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException{
        ObjectOutputStream out= new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(DEFAULT_FILE_NAME));
        for(Entry<Long, Page<byte[]>> entry : harDiskMap.entrySet()) {  
            Long key = entry.getKey();
            out.writeObject(harDiskMap.get(key));
        }
        out.close();        
    }

    public Page<byte[]> pageFault(Long pageId)throws FileNotFoundException,IOException{

        if(!this.harDiskMap.containsKey(pageId))
            this.harDiskMap.put(pageId, new Page<byte[]>( new byte[]{}, pageId));

        Page<byte[]> temp=this.harDiskMap.get(pageId);
        return temp;
    }

    public Page<byte[]> pageReplacement(Page<byte[]> moveToHdPage,Long moveToRamId) throws java.io.FileNotFoundException,java.io.IOException{
        harDiskMap.replace(moveToHdPage.getPageId(), moveToHdPage);
        writeHd();
        return pageFault(moveToRamId);
    }                  
}
```

Hi this the output

```
java.io.EOFException
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$PeekInputStream.readFully(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.readShort(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.hit.memoryunits.HardDisk.<init>(HardDisk.java:26)
    at com.hit.memoryunits.HardDisk.<clinit>(HardDisk.java:17)
    at com.hit.memoryunits.MemoryManagementUnitTest.testGetPages(MemoryManagementUnitTest.java:33)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
```

Comment: And... what's your question?

Comment: Why do I get the IOException error?

Comment: Reading the message and the stack trace of the exception would give a huge hint. But you didn't post it. Why is a mystery to me. Replace all your `System.out.println("SomeException);` by `e.printStackTrace()`, and read, and post what is printed. It explains exactly what and where the problem is.

Comment: I posted the error in the end of the first message can you understand  what is the problem ?

Comment: Yes. You get an EOFException. EOF means "End Of File". That's what happens when you try reading more objects than are available in the stream or, in your case, when you try to create an ObjectInputStream and nothing, not even the serialization header, can be found in the stream.

Comment: I can't figure out what to change in code ? Can you show waht to change ?